# Measuring time dilation (due to velocity) with an atomic clock

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, time-dilation, observers, atomic-clocks

Let there be a system in uniform motion to us at 36,000 mph, and let it have a clock onboard sending us signals as it ticks. Let us have our own clock, and let us account for variations due to that system's different locations (and the Doppler effect) as it sends each signal.

According to STR, if our clock is accurate enough, we measure this system's clock as running slower than ours due to time dilation. But 36,000 mph is (I *think*, though I've been known to make the "occasional" egregious error), only 0.0005% c, so we'd need accurate enough clocks to measure the difference.

My question is, for this speed, and in a practical test in which the system has say 10 seconds or so of uniform motion at 36,000 mph, how many ticks per second must the two clocks have in order to confirm the time dilation in that system?

Comment: Why can't you work it out for yourself`/

Comment: Marco, it's surely a simple problem for many people here, but obviously I'm not sure I've got the right answer, so I'm coming to SE, which is kinda the point of SE. Plus, there might be practical constraints I haven't thought of. So far, I've seen two replies (one since deleted) but no answer.

Comment: We are a bit shy of writing out answers for things that might be a homework problem or something like that.

Comment: Andrew, I see. All I can do is assure you it's not a HW problem. Also, it may require expertise from someone who knows about atomic clocks. My (bad?) math: 36,000 mph is 10 miles per second. 10/186,000 = 1/18,600, about 0.0005376% the speed of light. Call it 0.0005%. According to the LT, when 1 second elapses for the observer, about 0.9999998749 of a second is measured to elapse for the other system. After 100 seconds for the observer, the observed would be at only 99.99998749. Is that enough of a difference for the clocks to measure? (Or did I mess up the math?)

Comment: 1/18,600 is 0.005% not 0.0005%

Comment: Hi Anasker. Point taken. You seem to have answered your own question in your comment to Andrew. To measure the time dilation effect in the scenario you describe you would need clocks that could reliably measure a time difference of about 0.00001 seconds, which is a long time compared with the period of an atomic clock.

Comment: Time dilation due to relative motion has been successfully demonstrated at speeds down to a few cm/s https://www.forbes.com/sites/chadorzel/2015/07/22/three-experiments-that-show-relativity-is-real/

Comment: Thank you all! Marco, 0.00001 is very helpful, and yes, easily measured by atomic clocks. RC_23, thanks for catching the decimal place, and the cm/s reference is new to me. Thank you. I'll check it out.